# Possibility of staying within nucleus for a electron according to Uncertainty Principle

Tags: electrons, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-tunneling

> Academic Problem: *According to Uncertainty Principle, show that electron can't stay within nucleus.*

That's a general problem indeed. Anyway, we know that uncertainty of position in this case can't exceed $2 \times 10^{-14}$ m.

Now, $\triangle x$ and $\triangle p$ are the uncertainty of position and momentum respectively, $$\triangle x \times \triangle p = \frac {\hbar}{2}$$ $$\implies \triangle p = 2.64 \times 10^{-21} kg m s^{-1}$$

Thus, $ K_e = \frac {p^2}{2m} = 3.8295 \times 10^{-12} J = 23.93 MeV$

But experimental result shows that, energy of electron can't be greater than $4 MeV$. Suddenly I had a doubt on the effectiveness of 'Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle.'

[image]

The ground state of a quantum-mechanical system is its lowest-energy state. Now I won't talk about any excited state.

**But is there any possibility like electron fall down into the nucleus via quantum tunneling by radiating energy from its stationary orbit and when we observe such a thing, we see the 'Wavefunction Collapse' event?**

Maybe that's my misconception over the theme whereas quantum tunneling is possible only for a short amount of time and I don't know even whether 'Quantum Tunneling' permits such energy or not.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/426249/123208

Comment: @PM2Ring It was helpful but I ain't yet familiar with wavefunction $\psi$ and its mathematical application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electrons in an atom do “enter” the nucleus. There is no need for it to radiate first. In fact, electrons in the $s$ orbital for example, have wave functions that are a “maximum” at the nucleus (“centre of atom” - but note that quantum mechanically, at exactly $r=0$ the probability is not equal to one).

Electrons are not particles that can “fall” into the nucleus, but have quantized wavefunctions that are spread out in space.

All electron states overlap with the nucleus, so the concept of an electron "falling down into" the nucleus doesn’t make sense. Electrons are always partially in the nucleus.

If by your question you meant "Why can’t electrons get localized in the nucleus?" then the answer is still yes. Electrons can get localized in the nucleus, but it takes an interaction to make it happen.

This process is known as [electron capture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture). In electron capture, an electron is absorbed by a proton in the nucleus, turning the proton into a neutron.

The electron interacts with the proton and is absorbed to a point in the nucleus, and disappears (“collapses” to use your term) with the emission of an electron neutrino.

Note that this process is not something that happens with most atoms. An electron will only interact with a proton in the nucleus via electron capture if there are too many protons in the nucleus. When there are too many protons, some of the outer protons are loosely bound and more free to react with the electron.

Comment: Most electron states have a node at the nucleus, only *s* orbital electrons have an antinode there.

Comment: The captured electron doesn't *totally* disappear, that would violate lepton conservation. The weak interaction changes the flavor of an up quark to a down quark (which turns the proton into a neutron) but it also causes a complementary change in the electron, turning into a neutrino. And of course electric charge is also transferred during this process.